# VS 2015 Custom TFS Policy Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

We have some custom policies in TFS and are getting errors on the Pending Changes screen in VS 2015. The policies are working in VS 2013 and earlier.

> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.ChangesetComments, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom policies have to be compiled for the version of the .NET framework used by TFS 2015 / VS 2015.

Comment: .NET 4.6, of course. The version of .NET that's installed when you install VS 2015.

Comment: I'd suggest opening your custom policy project(s) in VS2015. Delete the references to all the TFS dlls and re-create the references, looking in the installed VS2015 instance instead of the previous (VS2013) location. Then rebuild with VS2015. This should ensure your policies are linking to the same versions of the dlls as the Visual Studio instance that is hosting them. (As Daniel says, you may also need to change the project settings to target .net 4.6 rather than an earlier .net version)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. But, installing TFS power tool solved my problem. What I have done was, Downloaded and installed TFS power tool for the Visual Studio version I'm using and restarted the machine. that's it the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with VS2013. Installing TFS Power Tools and restarting machine resolved the problem.